# Connection issue with chat bot deployed on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, botframework

I have deployed a Node.js bot (code from Github sample) on AWS and have configured CosmosDB on Azure. I also have configured ports to allow all incoming and outgoing traffic on AWS.

Now, if I run the node server on local and use emulator to communicate, I receive messages from the server. If I use node server running on AWS to connect, I get an error as attached:[image: Error on AWS console]

On emulator I see this - Error: The bot is remote, but the callback URL is localhost. Without tunneling software you will not receive replies.Connecting to bots hosted remotely

How do I resolve this? Do I need to install ngrok on EC2 machine as well?

Update 1: I have installed ngrok on local machine where I am running emulator.

Comment: Did you correctly configure your ngrok path for your emulator?

Comment: @GraceFeng Yes I did..

Comment: Your bot server port is 3978, but you're connecting to port 53504, strange thing is that I tested with connecting to wrong port, I can't get into the waterfall step.